# How do I grab values from a row in a database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

So I am using codeigniter and am currently trying to get the data from one row of a table let's call it table A, and place the values from that row and place it into table b.

I tried using the following:

```
$this->db->where('email', $this->session->userdata('email'));

$data = $this->db->get('table_A');

$this->db->insert('table_B', $data);
```

along with other variations but have not had any luck. Does the get() method not return values?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $this->db->get('table_A');

$newdata = array( 
'USER_EMAIL ' => $data->row()->USER_EMAIL , 
'USER_CLOCK_IN' => $data->row()->USER_CLOCK_IN 
)

$this->db->insert('table_B', $newdata);
```

Comment: what if I wanted to get more than one column

Comment: Like what i ANSWERED LAST TIME!
$this->db->insert('table_B', $data->results());

Comment: You should try it first.

Comment: okay. and I asked the person below the same thing. You have 'table_B_row'. what if table B is empty and does not have any rows

Comment: How come your table doesn't contain any row??

Comment: Can I see your 2 tables?!

Comment: it's an new empty table, it will get filled with the data taken from table A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98775/discussion-between-ddrossi93-and-felix-kamote).

Comment: Dunno how to use chat here

Comment: click automatically move this discussion to chat